# Apache Flink is it possible to use a ProcesingTimeTimer in a stream with an EventTime TimeCharacteristic

Tags: apache-flink

I have a stream of elements in an EventTime stream to a TumblingWindow to an AggregationFunction to a FlatMap which maintains state over aggregations and generates alarms

The elements are coming over a network and occasionally there is a delay in events so that the TumblingWindow does not close for some time.  In these cases there can be elements buffered in the window that when combined with what had been collected earlier would generate an alarm.  Is there a way to close a TumblingWindow early in such a scenario?

Is there a recommended pattern to follow for something like this.

I tried the following with no success ... should it have worked
I combined a ProcessFunction, a custom trigger and added a boolean flushSignal to the Element in the stream.  I inserted the  ProcessFunction upstream of the window and starting a processing time timer in it, from the processingElementMethod
           long timeout = ctx.timerService().currentProcessingTime() + 10000;
           ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(timeout);

and save the element that was passed in to be processed in the keyed state

When the timer expired in the onTimer method I retrieved the element from the keyedstate, set the flushSignal set to true and passed it to the onTimer collector.

In the trigger the intent was to in the onElement method return TriggerResult.FIRE.

However, the Element instance did not make it to the custom trigger. In the TumblingWindow.assignWindows method the timestamp is invalid.

Does the collector in ProcessFunction.onTimer need to be correlated with the  collector in the ProcessFunction.processElement?

Note that I element stream has time characteristic eventTime and the timer I am trying to use is a ProcessingTimeTimer, is that a problem?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Jim